# Binomial heap sibling - linked list reversal

Tags: linked-list, nodes, heap, siblings, binomial-heap

I don't understand the reversal of the list of a node `l` in a binomial heap:

```
Node* reverseList(Node* l) {
    //return reverseNode(l);
    if(l->sibling)
    {
        return reverseList(l->sibling);
        l->sibling->sibling = l;
    }
}
```

What does this mean? :

```
l->sibling->sibling = l;
```

The parent?

Comment: The code is nonsense, because the line `l->sibling->sibling = l` is never executed because the line before returns.

Comment: ok , is nonsense, but what l->sibling->sibling = l;       would return?

Comment: In C? It doesn't return anything. It sets the sibling field of the sibling field of l to be l.

Comment: So if a have 3 childs : x1,x2,x3 , if l==x1 , than l will be x3?

Comment: To make these into a decent question, please add the declaration of the type "Node", and include a working version of "reverseNode". Asking "How does this code work" when it doesn't work doesn't make much sense.

Comment: If so, if i have just 2 childs? x1,x2 and l==x1

Comment: i just don t understand what that code would result..

Comment: The value of `l` does not change. The `sibling` field of whatever `l->sibling` points to is set to `l`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `return` statement ends the execution of the function, so you are asking about *dead* code.

I would expect the function to actually be like this:

```
Node* reverseList(Node* l) {
    if (l->sibling)
    {
        Node* head = reverseList(l->sibling);
        l->sibling->sibling = l;
        l->sibling = NULL;
        return head;
    }
    return l;
}
```

To visualise this, let an example linked list consist of three nodes:

```
  l
  ↓
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: NULL │
│               │     │               │     │               │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘
```

When the function is called, we get into the `if` and make a recursive call. That new (second) execution context has its own local variables, and to distinguish them, I will add an accent to their names. So we have another `l'` variable:

```
  l                      l'
  ↓                      ↓
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: NULL │
│               │     │               │     │               │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘
```

Also that function's execution will make a recursive call:

```
  l                      l'                   l"
  ↓                      ↓                    ↓
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: NULL │
│               │     │               │     │               │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘
```

The latest (third) execution of the function gets `l'->sibling` as argument and will assign that to its own local variable `l"`. It will find that `l"->sibling` is `NULL`, and so it just returns the same pointer without making any alteration. At this moment the lifetime of the variable `l"` ends. The caller assigns the returned value to a local `head'` variable -- again the accent to make clear this happens in the second execution context:

```
  l                      l'                  
  ↓                      ↓                   
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: NULL │
│               │     │               │     │               │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘ 
                                              ↑
                                             head'
```

Now we get to the statement: `l'->sibling->sibling = l'`. That means an assignment is made to the `sibling` member of the last node, and so we get:

```
  l                      l'                  
  ↓                      ↓                   
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: ─┐   │
│               │     │               │ ◄───────────────┘   │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘ 
                                              ↑
                                             head'
```

Then we execute `l'->sibling = NULL`:

```
  l
  ↓ 
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: NULL │     │ sibling: ─┐   │
│               │     │               │ ◄───────────────┘   │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘ 
                                              ↑
                                             head'
```

Then we execute `return head'`. The variables of the second execution context end their lives (no more accents). The first execution context will assign the returned pointer to its own `head` variable:

```
  l
  ↓ 
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: NULL │     │ sibling: ─┐   │
│               │     │               │ ◄───────────────┘   │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘ 
                                              ↑
                                             head
```

Now we get to the statement: `l->sibling->sibling = l`. That means an assignment is made to the `sibling` member of the middle node, and so we get:

```
  l
  ↓ 
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: ─────────► │ sibling: ─┐   │     │ sibling: ─┐   │
│               │ ◄───────────────┘   │ ◄───────────────┘   │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘ 
                                              ↑
                                             head
```

We execute `l->sibling = NULL`:

```
  l
  ↓ 
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: NULL │     │ sibling: ─┐   │     │ sibling: ─┐   │
│               │ ◄───────────────┘   │ ◄───────────────┘   │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘ 
                                              ↑
                                             head
```

And finally, we return `head`. The local variables end their lifetimes, and so only the returned pointer is relevant:

```
┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐     ┌───────────────┐
│ sibling: NULL │     │ sibling: ─┐   │     │ sibling: ─┐   │
│               │ ◄───────────────┘   │ ◄───────────────┘   │
└───────────────┘     └───────────────┘     └───────────────┘ 
                                              ↑
                                             (returned)
```

You can see that the returned pointer is indeed referencing the reversed list.

Comment: thank you so much. Noi, i understand! <3

Comment: Good answer. Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

The code in the question is incorrect, this is the correct code

```
int RevertList(Node *h){
    if (h->sibling != NULL){
        RevertList(h->sibling);
        (h->sibling)->sibling = h;
    }
    else
        root = h;
}
```

`RevertList` is a helper-function used when a node is **deleted** from a Binomial Heap.

When a node is deleted, it’s child and their siblings are detached from the Binomial Heap Structure. The `RevertList` function reverses the order of the detached children, so they can be union-ed to the root list, in the correct order.

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/DeepthiTabithaBennet/TheDataStructuresSurvivalKit/blob/main/Heap/Binomial_Heap.cpp) code for better understanding of how this works!

Below is an example, from the CLRS Textbook

[image]